# Failed to Format Date Picker

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am using a date picker plugin (http://www.daterangepicker.com/) I change the format to single date picker using the following code

```
$('.firstappointment').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 2000,
});
```

I tried to format the date to Day/Month/Year using

```
dateformat: 'dd/mm/y',
format: 'dd/mm/y',
```

but unfortunately, it seems to be not working

Comment: How do you pass the desired time format to your date picker?

Comment: I used this Format: dateformat: 'dd/mm/y',
format: 'dd/mm/y',

Answer (score 0):

According to [this sample](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example2):

```
$('.firstappointment').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 2000,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that format in initialization, instead try apply event to convert the received data to desired format

```
  $('.firstappointment').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
  });
```

Comment: When I tried to pass a value based on formatted structure it displays "Invalid Date" how can I go about it Please?